# How to specify mixed-effects using lme4 in r for a within-subjects experiment

Tags: regression, r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

Now I want to regress the overall quality of the ideas (DV) on the source interacting with a continuous variable. I was advised to use the `lme4` package, but I am unsure how to specify the `ResponseID` and the idea number.

My model currently looks like this:

```
lmer_model_interaction <- lmer(overallquality_1 ~ Source * contibuousvariable + (1 | ResponseId) + (1 | Idea), data = final_long_data)
```

In other words, if i set the respondents and the ideas as fixed effects, do i use the lmer or regular lm_robust, clustering at the evaluator level? or i keep it as random effects, using the model specified above?

Comment: I'm voting to close since this is more a programming question than a statistics question. Its not clear here from your variables which each of these mean, but based off how you worded things, it sounds like "idea" is a fixed effect and should be entered as such rather than as a random effect.

Comment: This question was closed was off-topic but I think it's actually missing details to make it answerable. If the OP amends with relevant details (incl. about the experimental setup, all the variables and the goal for this analysis), and ideally with (a snippet of) the data, this could make a good applied stats question and I would vote to reopen it.

Comment: @dipetkov I would be open to reopening for similar reasons, if the focus is equally on understanding the statistics and not just the programming.

Comment: Thanks @dipetkov - i added some extra details.

Comment: That's a good start on the editing the question, thank you. However, it's still difficult to follow the description. For example, I don't understand what "identify value ideas of external origin less" means; it's not clear how overall quality is quantified (what's the scale?)... Please keep in mind that we don't anything about the situation but what you write in the question.

Comment: Also as @ShawnHemelstrand suggests, consider changing the title to emphasize the statistical problem you are working on and not the coding in R.